# How to call Json service from Wordpress blog php?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, service

Am trying to call outside JSON service in my wordpress blog.

I searched for plugins first I got JSON API [Json API Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/)
and WP REST API (WP API) [WP REST API Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/developers/) am not getting is these are the required plugins to call JSON services to my PHP wordpress blog. If these are the required am not getting how to call from this plugins as I have already installed this plugins in my blog.

I am trying to save user details on button click in my blog by calling Json service to store data in database and to get some data form JSON service to show on my wordpress page .

Please give me some information about my view of calling Json service in my blog.

Comment: Please provide some more details regarding your question. Why you want to use JSON ?

Comment: Can u please check my updated text - @Sachin Krishna

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON API User wordpress plugin, and do some hard code inside plugin.